# Source Versioning for Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, version-control, plugins, visual-studio-express

Is there any Visual Studio Express plug ins for source versioning? I am starting a project on my own and only have the Express version of Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The Express editions support neither the Add-Ins nor Source Control providers (SCC plug-ins). While there are ways to make this work, they are undocumented, violate the license and [have caused legal trouble before…](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2007/05/31/microsoft-vs-testdriven-net-31-may-2007.aspx)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 Express, sure

Answer (score 23):

Way I do this is I have TortosieHG installed and then in visual studios express i went to Tools>External Tools.

I created the following enteries:

```
Title: HG New Repositry 
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hgtk.exe
Arguments: --nofork init Initial
directory: $(SolutionDir)

Title: HG Commit 
Command: C:\Program  Files\TortoiseHg\hgtk.exe 
Arguments: --nofork init Initial directory: $(SolutionDir)
```

I then added the two external tools to the toolbar. Now I don't get as nice intergration as I would with the full version of visual studios but I can commit source code and create a source repository without leaving Visual Studios.

Answer (score 6):

You don't really need an integration/plugin. First is not supported but there are very good alternatives to make it work.

Whatever SCM you decide to use (SVN, [GIT](http://git-scm.com/), [PlasticSCM](http://www.plasticscm.com), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)) just use the "find changes" workflow:

- Do your changes
- Find your modifications within the tool you've chosen to use
- Commit

http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-find-changes-on-plastic-scm.html

Edit: PlasticSCM is free for up to 15 users since Nov 1st 2010.

Answer (score 5):

Visual studio 2012 Express offers an [express version of Team Foundation Server](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products).

Answer (score 2):

Source control integration is not supported in the Express editions of Visual Studio. Check out the feature comparison chart at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any plugins for Express versions of VS.  Googling 'Jamie Cansdale' is the canonical reference for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The VisualSVN manual says it works with all editions of Visual Studio - though I have not personally tried it. I know that none of Microsoft's Team Foundation Server stuff will work with Express.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN doesn't support Visual Studio Express editions. Visit here for more info http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, does the Express edition auto-check for file updates?  If so, just use TortoiseSVN and save yourself the money of upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You can get cloud based Team Foundation Service for free as long as your project has 5 or fewer members.  I've been using it for a few months now and it works great.  There are a some features of Team Foundation Server that are not available yet, but, hey, it's free.

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/